# Video is not playing on other peer-side in WebRTC Simple-Peer Angular 7

Tags: angular, webrtc, angular7, simple-peer

I am working on WebRTC and connecting two-peers on different browser pages, one peer which is initiator comes with this url `http://localhost:4200/#init` and other which is video receiver comes with this url `http://localhost:4200/`.
After building successful connection 1st peer share its video with the other but problem I am facing is other peer is not playing or receiving the video.

```
export class SimpPeerComponent implements OnInit {

  targetpeer: any;
  peer: any;
  stream: MediaStream

  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      // This peer is the initiator and transfering the streaming to the other connected peer 
      if (location.hash === '#init') {
        let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        this.peer = new SimplePeer({
          initiator: location.hash === '#init',
          stream: stream
        })
      }
      else {
        this.peer = new SimplePeer()
      }

      // triggers when signal is sent from remote
      this.peer.on('signal', function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      })

      this.peer.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Received Data: ' + data)
      })

      this.peer.on('stream', (stream) => {
        // got remote video stream, now let's show it in a video tag
        this.videoElement.srcObject = stream
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  connect() {
    this.peer.signal(this.targetpeer);
  }

  message() {
    this.peer.send('Hello world');
  }

  @ViewChild('myvideo') videoElementRef: ElementRef;
  get videoElement(): HTMLVideoElement {
    return this.videoElementRef.nativeElement
  }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
        <video #myvideo autoplay controls class="video mb-2"></video>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-sm mr-1" [(ngModel)]="targetpeer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="connect()">Connect</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="message()">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can be the problem? Please guide!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simple silly mistake I was doing that this is supported in only `chrome` browser now a days but I was running this in `Opera` and spend all my day to get this mistake out :D